# ElasticSearch Convert Rest Query for nested field to client Scala/Java code

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

I could not find the documentation on how to transform the nested query from the
ES official example into Scala/Java code

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "user.first": "Alice" }},
            { "match": { "user.last":  "Smith" }} 
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Scala I've tried

```
  import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders._
  ...

  val q = boolQuery()
  q.must(termQuery("user.first", "Alice"))
  q.must(termQuery("user.last", "White))
  nestedQuery("user", q, ScoreMode.None)
```

but when inspecting the resulted query it was not the same.

The resulting query is something similar to (cropped version of it since original query is much bigger):

```
 "nested" : {
                            "query" : {
                              "bool" : {
                                "must" : [
                                  {
                                    "match" : {
                                      "user.first" : {
                                        "query" : "Alice",
                                        "operator" : "OR",
                                        "prefix_length" : 0,
                                        "max_expansions" : 50,
                                        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
                                        "lenient" : false,
                                        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
                                        "boost" : 1.0
                                      }
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "match" : {
                                      "user.last" : {
                                        "query" : "Smith",
                                        "operator" : "OR",
                                        "prefix_length" : 0,
                                        "max_expansions" : 50,
                                        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
                                        "lenient" : false,
                                        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                                        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
                                        "boost" : 1.0
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                ],
                                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                                "boost" : 1.0
                              }
                            },
                            "path" : "user",
                            "ignore_unmapped" : false,
                            "score_mode" : "none",
                            "boost" : 1.0
                          }
                        }
```

The actual exception I am getting is in an unittest:

```
. java.io.NotSerializableException: org.elasticsearch.client.Response
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputSt[info] - should excluded keywords only *** FAILED ***
[info]   org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:176)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1933)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1910)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1667)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1624)
ream.java:1509)
    at java.io.Obje[info]   at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1594)
[info]   at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:1110)
```

Comment: can you please post output query by your Scala code. Because as i know Java client code add some default param as well when you print the final DSL query.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion . I've edited the post to include sample output (the actual query is much bigger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Scala code is generating correct query. basically what happen here is, it added some default parameter with values in query and due to that, it looks like your query is bigger compare to original query. This done by both Java and Scala elasticsearch client (might be other language client is doing same). Also, when you create DSL query in Kibana, runtime this all the default parameter added to your query.

Below are the parameters with default value in your query:

```
"operator": "OR",
"prefix_length": 0,
"max_expansions": 50,
"fuzzy_transpositions": true,
"lenient": false,
"zero_terms_query": "NONE",
"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
"boost": 1.0
```

Below I have removed all the default parameter which is added in your query by code:

```
{
    "nested": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "user.first": {
                                "query": "Alice"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "user.last": {
                                "query": "Smith"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "path": "user"
        
    }
}
```

Comment: @vpetrescu you have not added that exception in your question. so i thought that you are just asking for clarification. Please add exception details as well. what exception you are getting ?

Comment: thanks, I know about the extra default parameters. I was wondering about the addition of the "query" word.                        "match": {
                            "user.first": {
                                "query": "Alice"
                            }
                        }  versus simply "match": {"user.first": "Alice",..}

Comment: "match": { "user.first": { "query": "Alice" } } and "match": {"user.first": "Alice",..} both query are same. it is adding query clause as adding default parameter as well.

Comment: thanks! queries are indeed the same. The error was generated by other part of the code.